# Action Bar title in Scrolling Activity not updating after it is drawn

Tags: android, material-design

I created a new Scrolling Activity from Android Studio's activity gallery. However, I seem to only be able to set the title for it during onCreate. Setting the title anytime after doesn't seem to repaint the screen to reflect the new title.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setTitle("test 1");
}
```

Title bar after running the above code is "test 1".

However, if I run an asynctask and try to update the title later, or if I try to update the title on the press of a button, it does not update.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
    actionBar.setTitle("test 2");
    Log.v("TEST", actionBar.getTitle().toString());
}
```

This logs "test 2" but the title bar text does not update to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this issue with ScrollingActivity where setTitle was being ignored for updates. I found an answer here in this blog post on the [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

"you should call setTitle() on the CollapsingToolbarLayout, rather than on the Toolbar itself."

Ex: ((CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout)).setTitle(newtitle);